# ASP.NET Web API 401 when adding credential header

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511803/sending-message-with-401-asp-net-web-api?newreg=cf2d9cdbb8924899aa30f41834d64634); however, slightly different and the answers did not work for me (or the original asker it seems)

I have an asp.net web api project created in .NET Framework 4.5. I wanted to add basic authentication in which I verify the user credentials upon every request. I used code I found from a couple sites (I would post the links but I need more reputation to post more than 2 links) to create a BasicAuthenticationAttribute and come up with a working solution.

All this was working fine on localhost, but when I moved it to our GoDaddy shared hosting site it always returns unauthorized. This unauthorized response comes before my authorization and I have proven that by removing my authorization code, which still results in the unauthorized response. Now, the interesting thing is, if I don't add the user credentials in the request, it works fine. It's only when I add the credentials that I receive the unauthorized response.

To summarize that a little...

- localhost without credential headers: works
- localhost with credential headers: works
- GoDaddy without credential headers: works
- GoDaddy with credential headers: unauthorized

I have seen several posts outlining that forms authentication could be getting in the way and I need to enable anonymous authentication. All of which I've tried, but nothing has solved the issue. I have also tried removing the FormsAuthentication in the web.config by taking out the code that adds it in the first place, as well as telling it to remove forms authentication as noted [here](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/08/23/Basic-Authentication-with-WCF-Web-API-hosted-in-IIS-Getting-a-404-Disable-Forms-Authentication-Redirection.aspx).

Relevant parts of web.config (I have commented out authentication section, I've had it uncommented and commented with same results):

```
<!--<authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>-->

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="MyApplicationName" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider" cookieTimeout="30">
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="MyApplicationName"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Client code calling the service:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyUserName" + ":" + "MyPassword"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse("Basic " + credentials);

    var obj = new MyObject()
    {
        MyData...
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("<URI>", obj);
...
}
```

Unauthorized request:

```
POST <URI> HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic <encoded info>
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: <host>
Content-Length: 705
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<data>
```

Unauthorized response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="<host>"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 00:52:10 GMT
Content-Length: 1293

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `<authentication mode="None">` == "app will handle it"

Comment: I have tried this as well - just tried again for safe measure - but I get the same result.

Comment: Any ideas? I've spent 2.5 hours on the phone today with GoDaddy trying to figure this out and they're trying to give up on it.

Comment: Assuming you've checked/debugged your `ActionFilter` fully (it is being called, credentials are sent and authenticated properly, etc.) it seems to point to an IIS setting. Do you have bare metal and/or IIS Manager access (e.g. look at the IIS -> authentication settings)?

Comment: My ActionFilter gets called if there are no credential headers. If I add credential headers, it only gets to global.asax Application_BeginRequest, never the ActionFilter. I removed the ActionFilter I had just to make sure it didn't unauthenticate anybody. I added some code in the Application_BeginRequest to log the current authentication mode and it is logging "None". I logged: `(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication") as AuthenticationSection).Mode.ToString()`

Comment: Furthermore, I just discovered the method `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` in Global.asax so I logged when that get called and whether the user is authenticated or not. When the headers aren't sent, it gets called and it logs 'False' for Identity.IsAuthenticated. When I add the headers it doesn't get called. So somewhere between `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` it is returning a 401 when I add authentication headers.    And all I can see for IIS settings is that this app is set as the application root and Anonymous Access is enabled.

Comment: Can't repro, fired up a scaffolding webApi, added a basic auth `ActionFilterAttribute`, set the attribute on an action and I'm where you're at _locally_ - everything works even after fiddling with web.config (default setting is "none"), etc. Your last comment seems telling (points to server setting since it doesn't seem to even get to your application) - have you tried posting this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Just wanted to chime in - I am experiencing (apparently) the exact issue.  WebAPI, Basic Auth attribute applied directly to the Controller.  My debugging indicates that a request I send from Fiddler that includes the Authorization header returns a null for `actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization`.  Doesn't happen locally, starts happening on GoDaddy.  No progress yet.

Comment: Just validated exactly what you said...as soon as I pass an Authorization header, my code is not even invoked.  If I pass no Authorization header, my code is invoked and (logically) the `actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization` returns null.

Any updates would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching and testing I finally figured out the problem.

In GoDaddy's shared hosting environment, **Basic Authentication is automatically and permanently enabled on all IIS Applications**.  You can optionally check a box in GoDaddy's IIS Management web portal to enable Anonymous. If you do that, it is the equivalent of having both Basic and Anonymous enabled in IIS under the "Authentication" icon.

This is easy enough to recreate in local IIS.  The problem for me was that on my local machine, I did not have the Basic Authentication feature installed, so it wasn't even an option.  Once I installed it and enabled it, I got the exact symptom I was getting from GoDaddy.

Since IIS in this scenario is configured to look for Basic Authentication, it sees the Authorization header on your request and attempts to do the work instead of passing it to your code.  This makes sense, but isn't the desired behavior.

The desired behavior can only be achieved by disabling Basic Authentication on the IIS Application.  This is where GoDaddy's shared hosting becomes a pain - they won't or can't disable Basic Authentication.  **The answer I got was that I need a dedicated hosting environment if I want this level of control**.

**WORKAROUND** (edit)

If you are a stickler for following standards, stop reading :-).  If you change the *scheme* portion of the Authorization header to something other than Basic, IIS will ignore the header and pass it on through!  That means you can change to something like this:

`Authorization: Pickle cmFtc2V5amFjb2I6aXNfYV9yYWRfZHVkZQ==`

Then just change your code to look for Pickle and it should work (it worked for me in my tests).  Eat that, GoDaddy!

Comment: You just saved me countless hours of debugging. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I just spend almost a week in search for that problem. I was thinking about that but I  had no clue how to debug this issue. Your suggestion finally fixed it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had never figured out the issue and needed a solution so I had to alter the object the client sends to include the user name and a guid to identify them and have nothing for the authorization header. That's an interesting workaround. The info you wrote about basic authorization in iis helps in case we move to dedicated and experience the same issue, thanks!

Comment: The use of Pickle was a bit tongue-in-cheek :-) "Real" web APIs (Box, SalesForce, etc.) use the Authorization header with the scheme set to "Token" so that might be a bit more legit.

Oh, and just so I don't forget: always do this over SSL! /disclaimer